# How to give the user input when asked in java while executing the script through python

Tags: python, input, cmd, subprocess

I am creating a python script which does the following task:
1)list all files in directory
2) if the files found are of .java type then
3) it compiles the java file using subprocess.check_call
4) if there is no error it then executes the file using its class name which is same as file name

now some file requires an user input during run time.
That's exactly where I am stuck. My script compiles and runs the java program.
but whenever my java program asks for input,"Enter The Number :" , my script does not takes the input due to which following error is thrown:

Enter the Number

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

```
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:415)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)

at inp.main(inp.java:17)
```

I want that the screen should wait for my input and when i enter the number it resumes its execution

my java program is:

```
import java.io.*;
class inp
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Number");
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int b=10*n;
        System.out.println("T 10 multiple of Number is : "+b);
    }
}
```

my python script is :

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

s=os.getcwd()
s="codewar/media/"
print os.chdir(s)
t=os.getcwd()
print os.listdir(t)
for file in os.listdir(t):
    if file.endswith(".java"):
        proc=subprocess.check_call(['javac',file])
        print proc
        if proc==0:
            l=file.split(".")
            proc=subprocess.Popen(['java',l[0]],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            input=subprocess.Popen(['java',l[0]],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            print proc.stdout.read()
```

Please point the error or tell me a new way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to give the user input when asked in java while executing the script through python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from glob import glob
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call

wdir = "codewar/media"

# 1) list all .java files in directory
for path in glob(os.path.join(wdir, "*.java")):
    # 2) compile the java file
    if call(['javac', path]) != 0: # error
        continue
    # 3) if there is no error it then executes the file using its 
    # class name which is same as file name
    classname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    p = Popen(['java', '-cp', wdir, classname], 
              stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
              universal_newlines=True) # convert to text (on Python 3)
    out, err = p.communicate(input='12345')
    if p.returncode == 0:
        print('Got {result}'.format(result=out.strip().rpartition(' ')[2]))
    else: # error
        print('Error: exit code: {}, stderr: {}'.format(p.returncode, err))
```

The key [as @user2016436 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562602/4279) is to use `.communicate()` method here.

---

> But I want in such a way that while its running and displays enter a
>   number : the screen should wait for my input and when i enter the
>   number it resumes its execution

If you don't need to capture the output and you want to provide the input manually from the keyboard then you don't need to use `Popen(.., PIPE)` and `.communicate()`, just use `call()` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from glob import glob
from subprocess import call

wdir = "codewar/media"

# 1) list all .java files in directory
for path in glob(os.path.join(wdir, "*.java")):
    # 2) compile the java file
    if call(['javac', path]) != 0: # error
        continue
    # 3) if there is no error it then executes the file using its
    # class name which is same as file name
    classname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    rc = call(['java', '-cp', wdir, classname])
    if rc != 0:
        print('Error: classname: {} exit code: {}'.format(classname, rc))
```

Comment: I used your code but when I am running the script i get following error :Error: exit code: 1, stderr: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: check
Exception in thread "main" 
Error: exit code: 1, stderr: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: inp
Exception in thread "main"

Comment: @user3010409: I've added classpath to the java command so that the class could be found.

Comment: thats okay sir, But I want in such a way that while  its running and displays enter a number : the screen should wait for my input and when i enter the number it resumes its execution

Comment: don't put additional info in the comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: I did so, please help now.

Comment: It sounds like you just want the java program to input and output normally, however you are redirecting it with subprocess.PIPE.

Comment: @user3010409: have you replaced `Popen().communicate()` with the `call()` shown in the last example in the answer?

Comment: yes sir I did it just now.. but still am getting no fruitful result. :(

Comment: @user3010409: I've tested it with the `inp.java` from your question and it works as expected: if you run Python script (with `call()` and no `Popen()`) it prints the prompt and sits there until you enter something, and then it prints the result.

Comment: is there something like stdout or other thin that can display the outputs as well alongside??

Comment: Yeah there it is but very fast. it runs and asks number ,executes it and goes of within Milli seconds.

Comment: well I meant just little that it asks me input , I enter it and it even displays the output on the cmd but the fraction of seconds for which it dispays is like in milli seconds.. thats why I was asking..

Comment: if you want to pause the script then you could add `time.sleep(3)` at the end of the loop to sleep for around three seconds or `raw_input('Press Enter to continue..')` to wait for the Enter key before continue to the next java file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instead of:

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(['java',l[0]],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
input=subprocess.Popen(['java',l[0]],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

it should be:

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(['java',l[0]],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Secondly, use [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to communicate with the subprocess, i.e., feed it with input. In your example:

```
(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = proc.communicate('2')
```

will pass '2' to the subprocess, and return the stdout and stderr of the subprocess.

Comment: [Don't use a list argument together with shell=True](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347)

Comment: when I am doing the changes as suggested by you I am getting output as 0 0 and nothing else. Neither "enter your number" nor any message..